# How does Javascript scope changes to String.prototype?

Tags: javascript, scope, prototype

I just took over a NodeJS application. I notice that this function is repeated in almost every file:

```
String.prototype.replaceAll = function (find, replace) {
    var str = this;
    return str.replace(new RegExp(find.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&'), 'g'), replace);
};
```

I'm thinking this only needs to happen once?

I'm assuming that if I put this some place high in the code, in a file that is called for every page, then this change is global?

I'd like to think I can delete all but one of these functions.

Comment: It depends how your node app is called, but yes, in theory putting this in another module and requiring it at the entry point should be all you need to do.

Comment: It would have to be invoked once on every page. That may be why it exists in multiple files. Usually things of this kind are contained in util scripts that are included in every page, so that such a script should only need to be written once.